TelegramWebApp Отправка данных после закрытия приложения
У меня есть телеграм бот, и в нем есть WebApp. Проблема в том что у меня есть поля которые отправляют данные на сервер по таймеру (то есть я записываю всю информацию в массив и раз в 3 секунды отправляю на сервер), а мне хотелось бы сделать так чтобы они отправлялись после закрытия WebApp приложения. Я почитал и нашел инфу про sendBeacon() и использовать событие страницы beforeunload НО проблема в том что у меня PUT запрос а sendBeacon() не отправляет его. Можно конечно использовать метод fetch но говорят что это не надежно.
Что мне делать подскажите?
И да надо обязательно отправлять все после закрытия, вариант с кнопкой не подходит
